# Setting wallpaper programmatically always tiling image

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, .net-4.5

I have a piece of code to set the desktop wallpaper however the image is always being tiled instead of stretched.

```
using (RegistryKey rkWallPaper = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", true))
{
    rkWallPaper.SetValue("WallpaperStyle", 2);
    rkWallPaper.SetValue("TileWallpaper", 0);
}
return SystemParametersInfo(0x14, 0, imagePath, 0x01 | 0x02);
```

The registry values are being set correctly, however when I go to the `Personalize` screen I see that the setting is `Tiled`.

I'm running Windows 8.1 preview in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These registry values are strings, not integers.  You can tell from Regedit.exe, it shows the value as REG_SZ instead of REG_DWORD.  This ought to fix it:

```
  rkWallPaper.SetValue("WallpaperStyle", "2");
  rkWallPaper.SetValue("TileWallpaper", "0");
```

Note the added double quotes.